# Maven archetype - how to generate artifactId based on other property value?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I'm wondering if it's possible to force the `artifactId` property to match a specific pattern which includes a value from another property. For example, in my `archetype-metadata.xml` I have:

```
<requiredProperty key="customerId"/>
```

and I want the `artifactId` to always be in a form of `<customerId>-custom-api`. I tried to add:

```
<requiredProperty key="artifactId">
  <defaultValue>${customerId}-custom-api</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

but it didn't really work, since the order in which Maven resolves these values is apparently not guaranteed. Are there any other options?